# Compatibility issue between XNA and Windows 8

Tags: xna, windows-8

When I try to install XNA, I get the following error message :

```
Your version of XNA Game Studio 4.0 and below isn't compatible with this version of Windows.
```

Is it *really* impossible to use XNA on Windows 8 (VS2010 is installed) ? It seems very strange ...

Comment: If you use XNA you can't sell your game in the windows game store. I suggest using MonoGame to write identical to XNA which supports Linux and Mac in addition supports the metro features of DirectX allowing it to be sold in the new MS app store.

Comment: Actually I'm running on a personnal Windows 8 OS, and I have to work with XNA for some courses, so it's not really for a commercial purpose. Nice to know, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If someone ever have the same problem :

You have to install the latest version of Games for Windows Marketplace client ([here](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient)).