# XNA game does not compile on Windows 8.1

Tags: xna, windows-8.1

I recently moved my xna game project from a windows 7 computer to a new Windows 8.1 computer. I am still using Visual Studio 2010 Express. After overcoming the [xna installation troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700472/compatibility-issue-between-xna-and-windows-8) my game cannot be compiled on the new computer.

The error message reads "This application cannot be started because of a false application configuration". See the manifest file for possible errors."
However I cannot see anything wrong with manifest file. But I also don't know what is supposed to be in there.

If I start the compiled exe outside of VS 2010 a message box says "side-by-side configuration is invalid".

Comment: Is that the exact wording of the error? Because typing it with quotes into Google only returns this question. That, or it's just that rare.

Comment: It is not the exact wording. The language on my computer is german, so I had to roughly translate the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I picked this problem up after abandoning it for a while: I created a new xna project on the windows 8.1 computer and copying code and resources. Then it compiled fine.